# CSS styling on password input in ASP.NET not displaying

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm making a login form and am having trouble with the CSS not working on the password input control and the submit button. I'm using Bootstrap 3.0, and my code is below. All of the other form controls are displaying with the proper styling.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Password" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })               
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Here's an image of how it's displaying:

[Login Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dDIx.jpg)

The password input should look the same as the user name input, and the button should be the same width as the the inputs above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the helper method overload incorrectly. With your current code, razor will render the markup like this

```
<input htmlattributes="{ class = form-control, placeholder = Password }"
                                          id="Password" name="Password" type="password">
```

which is clearly incorrect!

The second parameter of the overload expects an object that contains the html attributes. But you are passing in an an object which has another object in the htmlAttributes property.

The solution is to use the pass the correct object. This should work

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password,
                             new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Password"  })
```